# Hovering over an image shows background-color, but the color covers the whole website

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make it possible that if an 'user' hovers over an image than some information of that particular image is shown, this seems to work, but when removing 'the pointer' off the image, my whole website gets a green background-color. I've tried many things like: *setting the 'position' of the information in absolute* and *Trying to do it without any background-color when hovering over the image, but the 'information' is shown in a different position on my website, instead of the wanted position.* I Hope I can be helped further!

```css
.Fiat500e,
.AIWAYS-U5,
.AUDI-Q4 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.Citroene-Jumpy,
.Renault-Twizy,
.KIA-EV6 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.Hyundai-Ioniq,
.Cupra-Born,
.MG-Marvel {
  width: 250px;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.Fiat500e:hover,
.Citroene-Jumpy:hover,
.Hyundai-Ioniq:hover,
.img__wrap:hover,
.AIWAYS-U5:hover,
.Renault-Twizy:hover,
.Cupra-Born:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.img__description {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  background: rgba(0, 207, 52, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 10;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ImagesCars {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#Achtergrond-Cars {
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Achtergrond-Cars">
  <div style="display:inline-table;" class="ImagesCars">
    <div class="img__wrap">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="Fiat500e">
      <p class="img__description"><br><strong>Fiat 500e</strong><br><br><strong>Price: &euro;24.900</strong><br><strong>Radius of action: 180km</strong><br><strong>Battery capacity: 24 kWh</strong><br><strong>Acceleration: 9,5s</strong><br><strong>Fast charge: 23min</strong><br><strong>Seats: 4</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Pay extra attention on the minimal part. Use the code snippet `<>` (Ctrl +M) and make it actually working that it shows the issue. I doubt that it is necessary to post over 100 lines of code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for your comment! I changed the code and made it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself: *While using `position:absolute;` on `.img__description`*, but *this shouldn't be the case for `img__wrap` the position must be: `position:relative`*

```
.img__description {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.img__wrap {
    position:relative;
}
```